# Missing panel icons in elementary OS Luna

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os, icons

Dropbox, Network (Wi-fi) and Mega icons are gone. I don't know how it happened, perhaps an apt-get update or something.

Those icons should be placed besides that volume icon.

What I have to do to get them back? I have Elementary OS Luna version, i think is based in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: FYI: Yes the top panel is called Wingpanel, the bottom one with your application icons is the dock called Plank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I found to get some icons back is by instaling super-wingpanel.

I had to install this ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update
sudo apt-get update
```

And then installed elementary os tweaks:

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Finally installed super-wingpanel:

```
sudo apt-get install super-wingpanel
```

Just logout and log in again and my missing icons are again.